# Displaying Mysql data using PHP gives me a blank page

Tags: php, css

I am trying to display a table containing data from my db in a php page.

No problems at all.

When I try to use css to make the table better looking the browser gives me simply a blank page.
Here's my code...
If I delete the id=csstest part after opening the table tag everything works, as soon as I add id=csstest I get a blank page...
What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php

include 'config.php';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to db");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select db");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT data, cur_timestamp FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Check your SQL query");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Tabella: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table id="csstest"><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($result);
?>
</table>
```

Comment: try `echo "<table id=\"csstest\"><tr>";`

Comment: Thank you so much!

If you write it as an answer I'll choose it as correct :)

Comment: Nah, just choose `The Jumping Frog`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following statement:

```
echo "<table id="csstest"><tr>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<table id=\"csstest\"><tr>";
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add slashes before your double quotes:

```
echo "<table id=\"csstest\"><tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table id="csstest"><tr>";
```

above code generates parse error and your error reporting is off so it just showing blank page
try on of the below method

```
echo "<table id='csstest'><tr>";
echo '<table id="csstest"><tr>';
echo "<table id=\"csstest\"><tr>";
```